# Eliminar letras antes de depois de um número

Tags: javascript, regex

Olá, tenho uma String (`var test`), e gostaria de realizar algumas operações nela. O resultado desejado é ***um número, precedido*** ou ***da letra*** ***p***, ***s***, ou ***ps*** (NÃO *sp*) (ex: ps1), e ***um número, seguido de qualquer letra de a-z***, em qualquer quantidade, porém sem repetir as mesmas letras (ex: p1abd, corresponderia, MAS p1abbd não porque houve repetição de uma das letras, a letra b. (Essa parte de evitar repetição não consegui realizar). Me pareceu ideal usar `test[i].match(/\b(p|s|ps)\d[a-z]*\b/)`, porém, como podem ver no 1º Exemplo, o array vem com 2 valores, sendo o segundo a(s) letra(s) antes do número, ***indesejável***, ***só quero um valor, o primeiro***. Me parece que isso tem a ver com o uso de parênteses, mas não consegui outra combinação que funcionasse. No 2º exemplo, aparece exatamente como eu quero, mas a regex está errada porque relaciona qualquer combinação das letras p e s, mas ***não relaciona as letras ps***. Já no 3º Exemplo desejo eliminar tudo ***exceto as letras após o número***, mas tive problemas provavelmente por causa do Array c/ dois valores. E no 4º Exemplo desejo eliminar tudo ***exceto o número entre as letras***. No caso do 3º e 4º Exemplos, sei que há maneiras mais simples de realizar isso, como por exemplo: `test[i].match(/\d/g).toString()`, para exibir apenas o número. Mas eu gostaria de saber, para fins de aprendizado, como isolar o número do padrão a ser eliminado, assim como fiz no 3º Exemplo. Tentei algo do tipo: `...replace(/[p|s|ps][^\d][a-z]*/, ''))`, mas não funcionou.

```
var test = 'xyz p1abc xyz; xyz s3de xyz; xyz ps2fgh xyz'; // p1abc, s3de, ps2fgh
test = test.split(';');

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
test[i] = test[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

// Exibir as letras 'p', 's', ou 'ps' ANTES do nº, e qualquer letra APÓS o nº em qualquer quantidade.
console.log(test[i].match(/\b(p|s|ps)\d[a-z]*\b/)); // 1º Exemplo
// Resultado:
Array [ "p1abc", "p" ] // repete a letra p
Array [ "s3de", "s" ] // repete a letra s
Array [ "ps2fgh", "ps" ] // repete as letras ps

console.log(test[i].match(/\b[p|s|ps]\d[a-z]*\b/)); // 2º Exemplo
// Só não funciona porque não inclui o 'ps'. Resultado:
Array [ "p1abc" ]
Array [ "s3de" ]
null

// Exibir só as letras APÓS o número. ([a-z]*) // 3º Exemplo
console.log(test[i].match(/\b[p|s|ps]\d[a-z]*\b/).toString().replace(/[p|s|ps]\d[^a-z]*/, ''));
// Novamente, só não funciona porque não inclui o 'ps'. Resultado:
TypeError: test[i].match(...) is null
"abc"
"de"

// Exibir só o número. (\d) // 4º Exemplo
console.log(test[i].match(/\b[p|s|ps]\d[a-z]*\b/).toString().replace(/[p|s|ps]\d[a-z]*/, ''));
// Para este não achei solução.    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa entender como funcionam os **grupos de captura**:

- O primeiro valor retornado é sempre o casamento **inteiro** (isso não tem como mudar);
- Para cada `(...)` na *regex*, um valor adicional é retornado, em índices consecutivos, correspondendo àquela parte da *regex*; pode ser vazio (ex.: `(a?)b` aplicado a `b` vai vir com o grupo vazio).
- Se você **não quer** que um grupo seja de captura, use `(?:...)`.

Exemplo:

```
\b(p|s|ps)(\d)([a-z]*)\b
```

Três grupos de captura. Alguns resultados possíveis:

```
p1abc ==> "p1abc", "p", "1", "abc"
ps2   ==> "ps2", "ps", "2", ""
```

Outro exemplo:

```
\b(?:p|s|ps)\d[a-z]*\b
```

Nenhum grupo de captura:

```
p1abc ==> "p1abc"
ps2   ==> "ps2"
```

Nesses três exemplos, vou capturar somente uma parte da string, e não as demais:

```
\b(p|s|ps)\d[a-z]*\b
    p1abc ==> "p1abc", "p"
    ps2   ==> "ps2", "ps"

\b(?:p|s|ps)(\d)[a-z]*\b
    p1abc ==> "p1abc", "1"
    ps2   ==> "ps2", "2"

\b(?:p|s|ps)\d([a-z]*)\b
    p1abc ==> "p1abc", "abc"
    ps2   ==> "ps2", ""
```

### Substituições

Uma vez que você estabeleceu grupos de captura na sua *regex*, além de retorná-los no método `match` você também pode referenciá-los e usá-los durante uma substituição, no méodo `replace`. Você faz isso usando `$n`, onde `n` é o índice do grupo (começando em `1`). Por exemplo, assumindo o padrão com os três grupos, digamos que você quer substituir o prefixo, o dígito ou o sufixo por "foo", mantendo o restante intacto:

```
"p1abc".replace(/\b(p|s|ps)(\d)([a-z]*)\b/, 'foo$2$3'); // foo1abc
"p1abc".replace(/\b(p|s|ps)(\d)([a-z]*)\b/, '$1foo$3'); // pfooabc
"p1abc".replace(/\b(p|s|ps)(\d)([a-z]*)\b/, '$1$2foo'); // p1foo
```

### Observações

- Se você realmente não puder usar grupos de captura, e precisar casar só uma parte da string, leia sobre [*lookarounds*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Essas *regexes*, por exemplo, casa só o prefixo, só o número e só o sufixo:

  ```
  \b(?:p|s|ps)(?=\d[a-z]*\b)
  (?<=\bp|\bs|\bps)\d(?=[a-z]*\b)
  (?<=\bp\d|\bs\d|\bps\d)[a-z]*\b
  ```

  Mas se puder evitar isso, evite, grupos de captura são bem mais simples de entender e de aplicar (e têm menos restrições que os *lookarounds* - por exemplo, JavaScript não suporta *lookbehinds*, e a grande maioria das linguagens só aceita *lookbehinds* de tamanho fixo).
- Sua tentativa `[p|s|ps]` não deu certo porque os colchetes casam somente um caractere, dentre aqueles listados. Seu exemplo casaria `p`, `s` ou `|`!
- Se você não quer que as letras se repitam no final, eu sugiro fazer isso de outra forma que não *regex*. **Teoricamente** é possível (é uma linguagem regular), mas na prática o número de estados seria igual ao número de combinações possíveis (pois a *regex* precisaria "se lembrar" das letras que já apareceram para não permitir que elas voltassem a aparecer). A performance provavelmente seria bem ruim...

  Mas... não é de todo impraticável! [Essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870549/520779) mostra um meio de se casar uma sequência de caracteres sem repetição, combinando um grupo de captura, um *backreference* (referência para um grupo já capturado) e um *lookahead* negativo:

  ```
  ^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!.*\1))*$
  ```

  Adaptado ao seu caso, com todos os grupos de captura (não dá pra se livrar do último, pelo menos, então chutei o balde e incluí todos...), ficaria assim:

  ```
  \b(p|s|ps)(\d)((?:([a-z])(?![a-z]*\4))*)\b
  ```

  Veja um [exemplo no rubular](http://rubular.com/r/zsZLyeWKoF): o trecho casado está destacado, e os grupos de captura de 1 a 3 mostram o prefixo, o dígito e o sufixo (o grupo 4 é inútil).

Comment: É mesmo necessário usar regex pra isso? Se você identificou o padrão, pegou suas partes com grupos de captura, então você consegue substituir/combinar do jeito que você quiser, simplesmente concatenando essas partes. De todo modo, atualizei a resposta com uma nota sobre substituições. Em resumo, você mantém o prefixo com `replace(/\b(p|s|ps)(\d)([a-z]*)\b/, '$1')` e o dígito com `replace(/\b(p|s|ps)(\d)([a-z]*)\b/, '$2')`, por exemplo (existem outras maneiras).

Comment: _@mgibsonbr_, Examinei bem sua explicação e tudo ficou claro p/ mim. Armazenei o resultado em `var s = test[i].match(\b(p|s|ps)(\d)((?:([a-z])(?!.*\4))*)\b);`, e agora acesso cada grupo de captura pelos seus índices. Ex: `s[0]` e/ou `s[2]`..., bem econômico. Valeu pela ajuda! Porém, quando o valor da variável **test** repete sequer uma única letra do sufixo alfabético (3º grupo de captura), não há correspondência. Ex: `var test = 'xyz p1abc cde` não corresponde por causa da letra **c** em **cde**, mesmo estando fora dos limites da busca.

Comment: De fato, o lookahead verifica até o final... Experimente substituir o `.` por outro `[a-z]`, assim ele deve parar de procurar repetições onde não deve: `\b(p|s|ps)(\d)((?:([a-z])(?![a-z]*\4))*)\b` ([exemplo](http://rubular.com/r/zsZLyeWKoF))